# Знак "Глас народа"

Tags: дефект, знаки

*Возможно это немного незначительно, но...*

В описании знака "Глас народа", как я думаю, допущена логическая ошибка. Текст таков:

> Использовать максимум 40 голосов в день

Для получения этого значка требуется проголосовать 40 раз, но так как есть слово максимум, следовательно можно набрать хоть 39, хоть 4, и получить знак.

Comment: 1. Ответы - в ответы. 2. Там смысл "Использовать максимальное количество голосов в день, а именно 40", а твои варианты это не отражают.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Достичь дневной лимит в 40 голосов